# Why can't OpenConnection() be called twice in one method?

Tags: c#, mysql, database-connection

Why can't I call OpenConnection() twice in one method? When I call it this error appears:

> The connection is already open.

I call it twice in `SelectDisPatient()` and `Count()`. See my code at `for (int index = 0; index < Count(); index++)`

This method `SelectDisPatient`:

```
public void SelectDisPatient(FrmVIRGO frm)
{
   string query = "SELECT id_pasien FROM tb_patient_information ";
   if (this.OpenConnection() == true)
   { //Create Command
      MySqlCommand cmd = new MySqlCommand(query, connection);
      //Create a data reader and Execute the command
      MySqlDataReader dataReader = cmd.ExecuteReader(CommandBehavior.CloseConnection);
      if (dataReader.HasRows)
      {
         for (int index = 0; index < Count(); index++)
         dataReader.Read();
         frm.tbName.Text = dataReader[0].ToString(); 
      } 
         //close Data Reader
         dataReader.Close();

         //close Connection
         this.CloseConnection();

    }
 }
```

This `Count()` method:

```
public int Count()
{
   string query = "SELECT Count(*) FROM tb_patient_information";
   int Count = -1;

   //Open Connection
   if (this.OpenConnection() == true)
   {
      //Create Mysql Command
      MySqlCommand cmd = new MySqlCommand(query, connection);

      //ExecuteScalar will return one value
      Count = int.Parse(cmd.ExecuteScalar()+"");

      //close Connection
      this.CloseConnection();

      return Count;
    }
    else
    {
       return Count;
    }
 }
```

But when I remove `(this.OpenConnection() == true)` in the `Count()` method it says I need to close the connection.

Comment: why do you want to open a connection twice ?

Comment: Put `dataReader.Close();` into your `for` loop

Comment: ^ or pool and reuse connections.

Comment: @CodeIgnoto please see for `(int index = 0; index < Count(); index++)` in _SelectDisPatient_ method I must call this twice..

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try:

```
public void SelectDisPatient(FrmVIRGO frm)
{
   int count =  Count();
   string query = "SELECT id_pasien FROM tb_patient_information ";
   if (this.OpenConnection() == true)
   { //Create Command
      MySqlCommand cmd = new MySqlCommand(query, connection);
      //Create a data reader and Execute the command
      MySqlDataReader dataReader = cmd.ExecuteReader(CommandBehavior.CloseConnection);
      if (dataReader.HasRows)
      {
         for (int index = 0; index < count ; index++)
         dataReader.Read();
         frm.tbName.Text = dataReader[0].ToString(); 
      } 
      //close Data Reader
      dataReader.Close();

      //close Connection
      this.CloseConnection();

    }
 }
```